# Why is my markers not being removed on leaflet app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using the leaflet api https://leafletjs.com/examples.html and when I click on my earthquakeMarkersControl button it creats the markers, but when I click again, it should remove the markers, my console log is returning the expected, but not removing the markers from the screen, does anyone know how to work with leaflet to help me?

There is a toggle (show/hide) controll where the markers should be removend when they are on screen or be placed when they are not, the step of placing markers is working, but can't understand why removing them is not working.

Here is my rep in case you want to check the code from there

https://github.com/vsrromero/gazetteerV3

my code

```
//* global variables

var homePosition = [];
var selectedCountryName = '';
var popup = L.popup();
var earthquakeMarkers = [];
var marker = null;
var markersVisible = false;
console.log('markersVisible initial state: ', markersVisible);

//* End of global variables

//* general functions 

//! Get the coordinates from a country name
async function getCoordinatesFromCountry(countryName) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('assets/php/openCage.php?countryName=' + countryName);
        const data = await response.json();
        const country = data.results[0].geometry;
        return [country.lat, country.lng];
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}

//! Check if a point is inside a polygon
function pointInPolygon(latitude, longitude, coordinates) {
    var isInPolygon = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        var polygon = coordinates[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < polygon.length; j++) {
            var ring = polygon[j];

            var intersect = false;
            for (var k = 0, l = ring.length - 1; k < ring.length; l = k++) {
                var xi = ring[k][0];
                var yi = ring[k][1];
                var xj = ring[l][0];
                var yj = ring[l][1];

                if (((yi > latitude) !== (yj > latitude)) && (longitude < (xj - xi) * (latitude - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi)) {
                    intersect = !intersect;
                }
            }

            if (intersect) {
                isInPolygon = !isInPolygon;
            }
        }
    }

    return isInPolygon;
}

//! Get the country name by latitude and longitude
function getCountryFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude, geoJSON) {
    for (var i = 0; i < geoJSON.features.length; i++) {
        var feature = geoJSON.features[i];
        if (pointInPolygon(latitude, longitude, feature.geometry.coordinates)) {
            updateCountryList();
            return feature.properties.name;
        }
    }
    console.log('No country found');
    return ""; // Retorna uma string vazia se nenhum país for encontrado
}

//! Get the country code by latitude and longitude
function getCountryCodeFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude, geoJSON) {
    for (var i = 0; i < geoJSON.features.length; i++) {
        var feature = geoJSON.features[i];
        if (pointInPolygon(latitude, longitude, feature.geometry.coordinates)) {
            return feature.properties.iso_a2;
        }
    }
    console.log('No country found');
    return ""; // Retorna uma string vazia se nenhum país for encontrado
}

function updateCountryList() {
    var selectElement = $('#countriesList select');

    $.getJSON('assets/php/getCountryList.php', function (data) {
        selectElement.empty(); // Limpa a lista antes de atualizá-la

        $.each(data, function (index, country) {
            var option = $('<option>').val(country.iso_a2).text(country.name);

            if (country.name === selectedCountryName) {
                option.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }

            selectElement.append(option);
        });
    });
}

async function renderInfoModal(selectedCountry, selectedCountryCode) {
    // implementation goes here
}

//! Get the country code from the selected country and render the info modal
function handleInfoButtonClick(selectedCountryName) {
    $.getJSON('assets/php/getCountryList.php', function (data) {
        var selectedCountryCode = '';
        $.each(data, function (index, country) {
            if (country.name === selectedCountryName) {
                selectedCountryCode = country.iso_a2;
            }
        });

        if (selectedCountryCode !== '') {
            renderInfoModal(selectedCountryName, selectedCountryCode);
        }
    });
}

function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(map);
}

//! classify the magnitude of an earthquake
function richterScale(magnitude) {
    switch (magnitude) {
        case magnitude < 3.0:
            return 'Microtremor';
        case magnitude < 4.0:
            return 'Minor earthquake';
        case magnitude < 5.0:
            return 'Moderate earthquake';
        case magnitude < 6.0:
            return 'Strong earthquake';
        case magnitude > 6.0:
            return 'Major earthquake';
        default:
            return 'Unknown';
    }
}



//* End of general functions

//* Leaflet helper functions



function toggleMarkers() {
    console.log('markersVisible initial function state: \n', markersVisible);
    if (markersVisible) {
        console.log('removing markers');
        removeMarkers();
        markersVisible = false;
        console.log(earthquakeMarkers);
        console.log('This state must be false: \n', markersVisible, '\n----------------------');
    } else {
        console.log('adding markers');
        addEarthquakes(59.3607741849963, 49.9028622252397, 1.7689121033873, -8.61772077108559);
        markersVisible = true;
        console.log(earthquakeMarkers);
        console.log('This state must be true: \n', markersVisible, '\n----------------------');
    }
}

function onMarkerClick(earthquake) {
    popup
        .setLatLng([earthquake.lat, earthquake.lng])
        .setContent(
            "Magnitude: " + earthquake.magnitude +
            "<br>Depth: " + earthquake.depth)
        .openOn(map);
}

//! Add earthquake markers to the map
async function addEarthquakes(north, south, east, west) {
    const response = await fetch('assets/php/earthquakes.php?north=' + north + '&south=' + south + '&east=' + east + '&west=' + west);
    const data = await response.json();
    data.data.forEach(function (earthquake) {
        var lat = earthquake.lat;
        var lng = earthquake.lng;

        // customize the marker
        var earthquakeIcon = L.divIcon({
            className: 'custom-marker-icon',
            html: '<i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney-crack"></i>',
            iconSize: [20, 20],
            iconAnchor: [20, 40]
        });

        // Crie um marcador usando as coordenadas lat e lng
        var marker = L.marker([lat, lng], { icon: earthquakeIcon });

        // Adiciona um evento de clique ao marcador para exibir as informações
        marker.on('click', function () {
            onMarkerClick(earthquake);
        });

        // Adicione o marcador à matriz earthquakeMarkers
        earthquakeMarkers.push(marker);

        // Adicione o marcador ao mapa
        marker.addTo(map);
    });
}

function removeMarkers() {
    if (marker) {
        map.removeLayer(marker);
        marker = null;
    }
    earthquakeMarkers = [];
}


//* End of Leaflet helper functions

//! Loading overlay
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#loading-overlay').fadeOut('slow');
});

// * Leaflet codes

//! Map instance and rendering
// map initialization
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 15);

// map layer
var mapLayer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 16,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});

mapLayer.addTo(map);
//! End of map instance and rendering

//! featureGroup object to store the GeoJSON layers
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

//! add layers from GeoJSON data to the featureGroup object
$.getJSON('assets/json/countryBorders.geo.json', function (data) {

    L.geoJSON(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
        }
    }).addTo(map);

});

// control buttons
var earthquakeMarkersControl = L.control();
var infoControl = L.control();
var weatherControl = L.control();

// button html
earthquakeMarkersControl.onAdd = function (map) {
    var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control');
    button.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney-crack"></i>';
    button.title = 'Show Earthquake Markers';
    button.classList.add('control-button');
    L.DomEvent.on(button, 'click', function () {
        toggleMarkers();
    });
    return button;
};

infoControl.onAdd = function (map) {
    var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control');
    button.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-info"></i>';
    button.title = 'Show Info';
    button.classList.add('control-button');
    L.DomEvent.on(button, 'click', function () {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
    });
    return button;
};

weatherControl.onAdd = function (map) {
    var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control');
    button.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-cloud-sun"></i>';
    button.title = 'Show Weather';
    button.classList.add('control-button');
    L.DomEvent.on(button, 'click', function () {
        $('#weatherModal').modal('show')
    });
    return button;
};

// add controls to map
earthquakeMarkersControl.addTo(map);
infoControl.addTo(map);
weatherControl.addTo(map);

//* End of Leaflet codes

/**
 * Sets the map view and adds a marker at the current location based on the geolocation data.
 * @param {Object} position - The geolocation position object containing latitude and longitude coordinates.
 */
function handleGeolocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    // Set map view to current location
    map.setView([latitude, longitude], 12);

    // Add a marker at the current location
    L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);


    //Retrieve country information based on the current location
    $.getJSON('assets/json/countryBorders.geo.json', function (geoJSONdata) {
        var selectedCountry = getCountryFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude, geoJSONdata);
        var selectedCountryCode = getCountryCodeFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude, geoJSONdata);

        // Get the country name by the current location
        selectedCountryName = getCountryFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude, geoJSONdata);

        // Remove existing layers from the map
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer !== featureGroup && layer !== mapLayer) {
                map.removeLayer(layer);
            }
        });

        // Highlight the selected country
        featureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer.feature.properties.name === selectedCountry) {
                layer.setStyle({ className: 'selected' });
                map.addLayer(layer);
            } else {
                layer.setStyle({ className: '' });
            }
        });

        // Fit the map to the bounds of the selected country
        var selectedLayer = featureGroup.getLayers().find(function (layer) {
            return layer.feature.properties.name === selectedCountry;
        });
        if (selectedLayer) {
            map.fitBounds(selectedLayer.getBounds());
        }

        map.addLayer(mapLayer);

        if (selectedCountryName !== '') {
            var selectedLayer = featureGroup.getLayers().find(function (layer) {
                return layer.feature.properties.name === selectedCountryName;
            });

            if (selectedLayer) {
                map.fitBounds(selectedLayer.getBounds());
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Handles the change event of the country list select element.
 * It updates the map and selected country based on the selected option.
 */
function handleCountryListChange() {
    var selectedCountryCodeList = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var selectedCountryList = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

    // Remove existing layers from the map
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer !== featureGroup && layer !== mapLayer) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        }
    });

    // Highlight the selected country
    featureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer.feature.properties.name === selectedCountryList) {
            layer.setStyle({ className: 'selected' });
            map.addLayer(layer);
        } else {
            layer.setStyle({ className: '' });
        }
    });

    // Fit the map to the bounds of the selected country
    var selectedLayer = featureGroup.getLayers().find(function (layer) {
        return layer.feature.properties.name === selectedCountryList;
    });
    if (selectedLayer) {
        map.fitBounds(selectedLayer.getBounds());
    }

    map.addLayer(mapLayer);
}

//! Loading overlay
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#loading-overlay').fadeOut('slow');
});

//! Get the current device location and set the map view to it
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGeolocation);
} else {
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}

//! Runs after the page is loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateCountryList();
});

//! Runs when the element with id="countriesList" is changed
$('#countriesList select').change(handleCountryListChange);

//* End of JQuery codes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem, the reason why it was not being removed is because I was trying to remove the marker variable instead of the `earthquakeMarkers` array. here is the solution

```js
function removeMarkers() {
    if (earthquakeMarkers.length > 0) {
        earthquakeMarkers.forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.remove();
        });
        earthquakeMarkers = [];
    }
}
```